# Why am I getting such low FPS in the Witcher 2?

Tags: steam, pc, the-witcher-2

I bought Witcher 2 during the Steam sales, and I don't know why I get so low FPS...
My specs are :

- MSI GE70
- Intel i7 4700MQ 2.4GHz
- GTX 765M 2Go
- 8Gb RAM
- HDD 7200 RPM

Low or High presets doesn't change anything !

Comment: Saying "high" computer while having a gtx 765m is wrong.

Comment: Seconded. Although we don't provide hardware suggestions or the like, it's glaringly obvious in this case that your 765m is the weak link.

Comment: With what @YUNOWORK said, you have a gtx 765m gfx card, so do not expect to much from it. The Witcher 2 is quite demanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be the NVidia 3D drivers that were not available for this game, and I should disable them.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you have tried to solve this problem, but my first thought would be to [update your Nvidia Graphics drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).

This is very unlikely but also try verifying your games files, maybe some essentials are missing. It will download the required files.

Comment: My drivers are already on the latest version !

Comment: Will try to verify my files :)